# Can adding/removing keys and indexes damage data in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm experimenting with various indexing settings for my mysql database.

I wonder though, by removing or adding indexes is there any possibility to damage data rows in any way? Obviously I realise that if I make any application queries fail, that can cause bad rows. I'm more talking just about the structural queries themselves.

Or will I simply affect the efficiency of the database?

I just want to know if I have safety to experiment or if I have to be cautious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data isn't in `phpmyadmin`, it's in `mysql`. Adding/removing an index will not affect your data integrity by default. With a unique index, and using the `ignore` keyword it can.

That said - you should always have a backup of your data, it's easy to run a test like:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 LIKE t;
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t;
ALTER TABLE t1 CREATE INDEX ...;
```

Then compare the difference in tables (perhaps a `COUNT` is fine in your case).

Comment: I see, so what you suggest is creating a temporary copy of the table as a sandbox....

Comment: That's always wise, better to be safe than sorry. Also, it may allow you to move faster as you wont have to wait for answers on SO :)

Comment: I don't mind waiting for answers. I love having someone else's input/views on topics. This is a very good suggestion.....seems obvious now I think about it.....

Comment: Could you tell me what happens if I use unique or ignore? What damage can occur?

Comment: :) With regards to the other answer, adding an index doesn't bring a server to its knees necessarily but it will create a lock on the table. You can avoid this by using `pt-online-schema-change` from the percona toolkit, or by applying the change on a slave and promoting it.

Comment: @Martin thank god my application isn't being pinged enough yet to be too worried about that yet!! :)

Comment: Sure, if you have a table with duplicates (say, a user_id column, and two rows with `5` as the value) and then you attempt to create a unique index on the table it will fail. You can override this by using `alter ignore table create index ...` and it will remove the duplicate rows for you. This is the only way I'm aware of you could compromise your data integrity by creating an index

Comment: Ok, so applying a unique to a column that has duplicates will cause the table to freeze up completely? Or rows will be lost somehow?

Comment: The rows will be removed (or lost). Not too sure what you mean by freeze, if you mean lock, then that applies to creating any index.

Comment: Ah, so it will keep the first instance it comes across and then delete any duplicates after that. That's very good to know thank you. Now I will experiment safely in my sandbox table hehe :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding/removing indexes is safe in terms of the rows in your table. However as you note, too many indexes or poorly constructed indexes can be (very) detrimental to performance.  Likewise, adding indexes on large tables can be a very expensive process, and can bring a MySQL server to its knees, so you're better off not "experimenting" on production tables.

Comment: Take a look at `pt-online-schema-change`, it's a good way to alleviate this once you have confirmed you do want the index